# Sorting DataFrame elements descendingly grouping by another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataFrame:

```
page_id   date
1        2018-01-01
1        2018-02-01
1        2018-03-01
2        2018-02-01
2        2018-03-01
3        2019-01-01
4        2019-04-01
4        2019-05-01
```

As you can see, the different page_ids are ordered ascendingly by date. What I want is to have them ordered descendengly, as follows:

```
 page_id   date
 1        2018-03-01
 1        2018-02-01
 1        2018-01-01
 2        2018-03-01
 2        2018-02-01
 3        2019-01-01
 4        2019-05-01
 4        2019-04-01
```

Note that the descending order is only among same page_ids, so sorting the whole dataframe wouldn't work, I first need to **group by page_id**. I've tried some options but I never get an output like the one I just showed.

Any tips on what would be the fastest way to do this will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I've tried doing:

```
data = data.groupby('page_id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('date', ascending=False))
```

But Then I get an error when doing do reset_index(), so I don't get an output like the one I said is the expected output.

Comment: You are stating in your question: "I've tried some options..." Please, provide these options you tried.

Comment: The `sort_values` method is all you need. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values. The `ascending` argument can be a list like `[True, False]` to signify ascending on the first column but not ascending on the second. so `df.sort_values(['page_id', 'date'], ascending=[True, False])`

Comment: This worked! I was grouping by page_id when it wasn't really necessary. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Try: reset_index(drop=True)